# Call two different function.js depending on page

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to find how I can call 2 different function.js depending of the page.

When on "home", I want to load "function_2.js", and on the other pages of my website the original "function.js".

I need to change something in my function.php but I can't figure out what.

Can anybody make a suggestion to what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my code

```
if(is_front_page()) { 
    add_action('wp_footer', 'handle_script', 200);
    function handle_script(){
        $templatedir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
            $scripts .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$templatedir.'/_/js/functions_2.js"></script>'."\n"; 
        echo $scripts;
    }
}else{ 
    add_action('wp_footer', 'handle_script', 200);
    function handle_script(){
        $templatedir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
            $scripts .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$templatedir.'/_/js/functions.js"></script>'."\n";
        echo $scripts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add code to comments. Such large amounts of code is unreadable. You should file an [edit] and add all relevant code/info directly to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write conditionals in your functions.php file to conditionally load the javascript files. For example:

```
function theme_scripts() {
     // If this is the home page, run this script
     if(is_home()) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'example-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path/to/file.js');
     }
     // Otherwise, run this script
     else {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'other-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path/to/file.js');
     }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Codex page for home page conditional can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home).
The Codex page for conditionals in general can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).
And you can find info on enqueuing scripts [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: You should wrap that example in a function and show how to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

i tried this inside my function.php, but I still get the same scripts loaded on every pages... what am I doin wrong ?
see below... sorry I can't format my code

Comment: if(is_front_page())  { add_action('wp_footer', 'handle_script', 200); function handle_script(){ $templatedir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$scripts .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$templatedir.'/_/js/functions_2.js"></script>'."\n";
echo $scripts;}}
else {
add_action('wp_footer', 'handle_script', 200);function handle_script(){$templatedir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();$scripts .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$templatedir.'/_/js/functions.js"></script>'."\n";echo $scripts;}}

Comment: I've updated my code to include the overall function that this should be wrapped in before you can use it in your functions.php file. The previous code goes into a function (usually called something like 'theme-name_scripts'). You'll then utilize the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook in order to call the function in your theme. See the Codex page I linked to on enqueuing scripts for more information and clarification on what exactly this does. Otherwise, you should be able to drop this into your functions.php file, change the path names, etc.

Comment: @user2882154 Replace the code you are using with mine. You should be using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of the `wp_footer` hook in order to insert scripts into your theme. [This tutorial might also help](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/#.U6hsRY1dWT4).

Comment: @user2882154 Please don't add large amounts of code in the comments section. Please file [an edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/151530/edit) to your question and add all relevant info directly to your question. Code in comments are unreadable. Thanks

Comment: @TimMcClure I updated your code to use `wp_enqueue_script` which is used to enqueue scripts, not `wp_enqueue_style` which is used to enqueue styles. If you are not happy with my update, then simply roll back my changes :-)

Comment: @user2882154 Check updated code